# Last record in Model. Using Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-entities

```
from stu in Students
where stu.Department == 'CS'
select stu
```

Above is the linq query. I want return all the students of CS department and show them in View. To View i'm passing a model Student whose result is returned by this query. While on view i want to add comments option(Comment link) so that i can add comments for the first student. So can someone please tell me how can i detect that this is the record of first student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Details:** The below shows how to get all students in the specific department as well as get the first student from that query result. Use Take to get the first element: [Take Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx)

```
var students = from stu in Students
where stu.Department == 'CS'
select stu;

var firstStudent = students.Take(1);
```